# Bootstrap 5 tab with form select, works in Firefox but not in Chrome or Safari

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have tab's that I want to select with a form select.

When I change the selection in the form select in Firefox, the tab changes. When I do the same in Chrome or Safari, nothing happens.

Why does the following work in Firefox but not in Chrome or Safari?

```
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <select class="form-select nav nav-pills" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
        <option selected="selected" value="0" class="active" id="pills-0-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-0" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-0" aria-selected="true">
            One
        </option>
        <option value="1" class="" id="pills-1-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-1" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-1" aria-selected="false">
            Two
        </option>
        <option value="2" class="" id="pills-2-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-2" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-2" aria-selected="false">
            Three
        </option>
        </select>
    </form> 
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-0" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-0-tab" tabindex="0">
            One
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade " id="pills-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-1-tab" tabindex="1">
            Two
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade " id="pills-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-2-tab" tabindex="2">
            Three
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade " id="pills-3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-3-tab" tabindex="3">
            Four
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check F12 Developer Tools, Console tab for errors. Also, edit your question and add more details about what exactly you expect to happen that isn't happening.

Comment: The chrome console shows no errors